# GROUPBy AND ORDER BY not working together

Tags: php, mysql

I have records like this

[image]

here is my query

```
SELECT   `Chat`.`id`, 
         `Chat`.`sender_id`, 
         `Chat`.`receiver_id`, 
         `Chat`.`message`, 
         `Chat`.`datetime`, 
         `Chat`.`converstation_id` 
FROM     `gopher`.`chat` AS `Chat` 
WHERE    ((`Chat`.`sender_id` = 10) 
OR       (`Chat`.`receiver_id` = 10)) 
GROUP BY converstation_id 
ORDER BY `Chat`.`id` DESC
```

But here order now is not working and this is the result I am getting after running this above query

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the `GROUP BY conversation_id`.

Comment: `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1` that's it. why do you need `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: What are you expecting / wanting to happen?

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions. Bad. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry what I want is that to get only one row in decending order but group by converstation_id. Because I don't need multiple rows

Comment: @prakashtank If I use Limit 1 then it will fetch only one record. see if there are three rows with converstation_id = 10 and two rows of converstation_id = 12. then I want two rows? How Will I get it

Comment: Take a look at the related questions. They are SURE to answer your problem.

Comment: @hellosheikh : you mean sender_id?

Comment: @prakashtank No I mean converstation_id. Actually I am giving a unique id to each two person communications

Answer (score 2):

You have not used any aggregate function , so your `group by` is just returning 1st data set. There are several ways to fix it

1. Remove group by  and just use order by if we you want to sort by conversation_id
2. Use aggregate function

Comment: I need only one result thats why

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT   `Chat`.`id`, 
         `Chat`.`sender_id`, 
         `Chat`.`receiver_id`, 
         `Chat`.`message`, 
         `Chat`.`datetime`, 
         `Chat`.`converstation_id` 
FROM `gopher`.`chat` AS `Chat` 
WHERE ((`Chat`.`sender_id` = 10) OR (`Chat`.`receiver_id` = 10))
GROUP BY converstation_id
ORDER BY `Chat`.`id` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```